# Does sharing with Facebook's Android's SDK really require android:exported="true"

Tags: android-manifest, facebook-android-sdk

**TL;DR**:

Is it a must to specify `android:exported="true"` for Facebook sharing, or can I use the safer `android:exported="false"`?

**Background**:

I followed the official docs on [Sharing on Android](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/android) where it says in the *Prerequisites* section:

> You also need to set up a ContentProvider in your AndroidManifest.xml where {APP_ID} is your app ID:

```
<provider android:authorities="com.facebook.app.FacebookContentProvider{APP_ID}"
          android:name="com.facebook.FacebookContentProvider"
          android:exported="true"/>
```

This works fine, however the line `android:exported="true"` gives a warning:

> Exported content providers can provide access to potentially sensitive data

From reading around, I understand this warning is about a potential security threat. So I changed that line to `android:exported="false"` and re-ran my app, which ran as expected with the Facebook sharing working well too.

So, can I get away with `android:exported="false"`, or will this be a problem in the future, perhaps when I deploy my app to Google Play?

Answer (score 0):

For my work place, we also are very very careful with android:exported="true". Generally, you can just leave it as android:exported="false" because you don't want **other applications** to access your app through the contentProviderId of that application. However, with the android:exported="false", applications that share your providerId (your other applications) will still be able to access it, but otherwise they can't.

Comment: I understand that it is better to use `android:exported="true"` my question is, why does Facebook explicitly specify `android:exported="true"` as a requirement for sharing when it seems `android:exported="false"` works too?

Comment: I believe any provider will have it explicitly specify the android:extra="true" because they would like you to have those things exposed... Not completely sure.